# Is it possible to select numeric characters only from a VARCHAR field in MySQL without the use of a custom function?

Tags: mysql

I'm importing data to a 3rd party CRM and the restrictions on the phone number field are tighter than those of the source database (MySQL). I would like to grab the first 10 numeric characters in the select. I don't have flexibility to sanitize the existing data. I can only work with what is there. All I can find in forums so far seems to be creating a custom function. Is a custom function the only way? The environment is MySQL 5.7.19.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp

Comment: You could use [REGEXP_SUBSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) if you upgrade to MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.7, here's how I'd do it:

```
SELECT LEFT(mycolumn, 10)+0 FROM ...
```

The builtin function LEFT() uses only the first N characters.

The `+0` makes sure to cast it to a number, just in case the first N characters include some non-numeric characters. Casting to a numeric in MySQL just uses the leftmost number characters, and when it reaches a non-numeric character, ignores the rest.

---

You can get rid of hyphens first, then use the result of that as I showed above:

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(mycolumn, '-', ''), 10)+0 FROM ...
```

Comment: That would work except it is cutting most records after the first 3 digits as the 4th character on most of the records is a hyphen. Good thought though!